# Не добавляется класс к дочерним элементам

Tags: javascript, jquery

При клике по элементу должен добавиться класс open к его дочерним элементам но почему то не срабатывает. Вот код:

```
$('.in20 .hid').click(function () {
$(this).children('.hid-content').toggleClass("open").css('display: block');
$(document).bind('click', HandlerPar);
});
function HandlerPar(e) {
if (!$(e.target).hasClass("in20") &&
    $(e.target).parents(".in20").length === 0) 
{
    $(".hid-content").removeClass("open");
    $(document).unbind('click', HandlerPar);
 }
} 


  //html
  <form method="get" action="" class="in20">
        <div class="in19">     <!---->
            <div class=" ">  <!--in16-->
  <div class="in17 hid"><b>[`Price`] <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></b></div>
  <div class="hid-content" style="display:none;">
  <div class="flex-prices slider">
   <input type="text" class="min" name="price_min">
   <input type="text" class="max" name="price_max">{*{$c.sign} *} </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class=""> <!--in18-->
            <div class="in17 hid"><b><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></b></div>
            <div class="hid-content" style="display:none;">
            <span style="display: none">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{$filter.code}[]" > {$v}
                </label>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="b_reset1">
        <input type="submit" class="in21" value="[`Filter products`]">
        <div class="b_reset2" onclick="window.location='/category/{$category.url|escape}'">Сбросить фильтр</div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

замените:

```
$(this).children('.hid-content').toggleClass("open").css('display: block');
```

на:

```
$(this).find('.hid-content').toggleClass("open").css('display: block');
```

.children() [Возвращает все дочерние элементы выбранных элементов](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

.find() [Осуществляет поиск элементов внутри уже выбранных элементов](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: Спасибо, сделал немного по своему через siblings. Но сейчас проблема в том что при клике на соседнии блоки не зыкрываются блоки которые открылись до этого

Comment: Вы замудрили свой обработчик с toggleClass и bind. Просто по клику на $('.in20 .hid') сперва делайте removeClass('open') для всех .hid-content а затем addClass('open')  на туда, куда вам нужно. И bind станет не нужен.